# Do Free Comic Book Day comics from DC or Marvel contain important plot?

Tags: marvel, dc

If they do, will they sell them in the future? I'm asking because I'm worried that there might be an important plot point in a series I'm following, and I might not be able to get the free comic. I have just begun collecting, that's why I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.  If you are a perfectionist and need to read every issue for every mini series or event comic, then you will probably want to pick these issues up.  They are always available at your local comic shop or you can find them online.

However, even though these Free Comic Book Day issues usually do contain important plot points for a future mini series or event comic, their real purpose is to get both avid comic book readers and non-comic book readers excited about the upcoming story and comic books in general.  Any plot points brought up in the FCBD issue are almost always either re-hashed out in the first issues of the mini series or ongoing comic that they are for.  Really these FCBD issues are best looked at as "prequel" comics.

A good example of this is DC's Free Comic Book day issue for their "Futures End" weekly series that came out a few years ago: http://comicvine.gamespot.com/the-new-52-futures-end-0/4000-452026/

The Free Comic Book Day issue focused mostly on back story and hints at the larger plot (all explained again in issue #1).  Also, it is important to note that a lot of these FCBD issues are either not numbered (the case with Marvel's new Civil War II FCBD issue) or are numbered as #0 (which is the case with DC's Future's End FCBD issue).

These FCBD issues are more like promotional materials to get readers excited for the book, than a key issue in a story.  I think they are always a fun read and they generally do a good job at getting readers excited for a comic book, but I would not consider them "must read" books and you will not be lost going into a mini series or ongoing series if you have not read these FCBD issues.